# Moving a .aspx site over to nginx, need to server .aspx as static files or rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx

I have a simple CMS site that was written in asp.net.
My site looks like:

```
www.example.com/
www.example.com/content/index.aspx
www.example.com/content/get.aspx?id=234  (loads an article)
```

It uses a database currently, but I am going to dump all the content to file, and then I can just pull the contents of the file based on the id=234 value.

I want to move this site over to my ubuntu nginx server.

What options do I have? Suggestions?

I want to keep the URL structure exactly how it is now, how can I do this?
Would this be any easier using apache?

**Note: just to clarify, I am moving away from .net and am just going to make the content as static files, I just need the urls to map w/o any redirects etc.**

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could host the Asp.Net web appliction under Mono on Ubuntu, keeping it in .Net: - http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

I know you state that you wish to place the content on your Ubuntu sever, but it should be perfectly possible to keep the site hosted the way it is, and have the Nginx server point to your current web server: http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2010/01/13/asp-net-performance-part-5-nginx.aspx

Comment: I don't want to serve it under .net anymore, just static files.